# Getting cert error even after adding CA cert to trust store on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, certificate, openshift

I am trying to set up Openshift 4.9 and running into issues configuring the mirror registry. I have narrowed down the issue to cert error with quay.io

```
$ wget "https://quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-release:4.8.15-x86_64"
--2021-10-25 16:57:27-- https://quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-release:4.8.15-x86_64
Resolving quay.io (quay.io)... 35.172.159.14, 34.224.196.162, 3.216.152.103, ...
Connecting to quay.io (quay.io)|35.172.159.14|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of âquay.ioâ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of âquay.ioâ has been revoked.
```

I have downloaded the cert chain from quay.io and copied it to

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
```

Then I ran `update-ca-trust` as well as `update-ca-trust extract`

I checked the bundle and certs are present.

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
```

However, I keep getting the cert for quay.io is not trusted.
Any pointers to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: can you check the certificate expiry with `openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert -noout -text`?

Comment: Have you checked the file `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Answer (score 0):

Two things may help:
First of all, make sure you added the right CA file to the anchors folder:

```
DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA   Self-signed
Fingerprint SHA256: 7431e5f4c3c1ce4690774f0b61e05440883ba9a01ed00ba6abd7806ed3b118cf
Pin SHA256: WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=
```

Then check the result in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`